# Does SQL Server work on SATA drives?

Tags: sql-server

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979523(v=vs.85).aspx says that Windows does not support write-through on SATA drives: "Starting in Vista, Windows supports the FUA flag only for SCSI and Fiber Channel disks." http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/1/e/f1ecc20c-85ee-4d73-baba-f87200e8dbc2/sql_server_io_reliability_program_review_requirements.pdf says that SQL Server requires FUA.  It seems that SQL on SATA drives doesnt't work.  Transactions aren't durable, probably.  What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the word Vista doesn't even appear on that page.

Comment: @BrentOzar It's the third link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd979523(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "work". I'm running a non-production environment of SQL Server on this computer that uses SATA drives.

Comment: @JoeObbish I mean that commits are not durable because SQL Server uses the FUA flag to write the log file.

Comment: http://bobsql.com/sql-server-on-linux-forced-unit-access-fua-internals/ detailed info

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different questions in here.

**Do all drives safely flush data to disk when power is lost?** No. Consumer-grade computers and drives often don't include their own battery backups or capacitors. If power is lost without warning, they can lose data that the OS thinks was safely flushed to disk, but is actually still living in cache.

**Does SQL Server work on those systems?** Yes, but its ability to recover from a power failure is unpredictable. It's fine for things like development environments where you should be checking your work into source control anyway.

**Should SQL Server go in production on those systems?** It depends on what you're using the data for, whether the data is recoverable (for example, TempDB is perfectly fine on drives like this, since it doesn't survive a restart anyway), whether the data center has its own redundant battery backups, etc.

Comment: AFAIU, even without battery or capacitors, good drives honor write-through requests. Rereading the links, I think Vista+ avoid write-through in SATA drives only for filesystem metadata. Programs are free to continue using it if they trust the drives.

Comment: Bad news - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/11/18/dont-do-it-consumer-ssd/